# Trigger on the same values in a column on sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

Please help me, I wanted to write a trigger that would handle the same values in a column and generate an error. My trigger gives an error when the values are the same, but after updating the value, it still gives the same values

```
USE [Uchet_zhitelei]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[CheckINNUnique]    Script Date: 08.03.2023 20:22:51 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[CheckINNUnique]
ON [dbo].[Residents]
FOR UPDATE
AS
BEGIN

  --declare @inn INT

  --select @inn = (select top 1 INN from Residents order by ID desc)

    IF exists (select r.inn from Residents r, inserted i where i.INN = r.inn) 
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('Такой ИНН уже существует в базе', 16, 1);
        ROLLBACK;
    END
END
```

Comment: wouldn't it  be easier to make inn unique

Comment: Using a trigger here is the wrong tool. This should be a unique constraint.

Comment: I need it to give an error . I have been given this task.

Comment: If you are determined to use a trigger (not recommended) you will need to also create a second trigger. Your trigger posted here is only for updates which means you could insert a duplicate value. I would also suggest that you use explicit joins instead of comma separated tables.

Answer (score 0):

Using a unique index is a much better approach to this.

```
alter table Residents
add constraint UX_Residents_Inn unique (Inn)
```

You will get an error message when a second value is detected.

Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 10
Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UQ_Residents_Inn'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Residents'. The duplicate key value is (SomeValue).

Comment: I need it to write "such an INN already exists"Not just an error.

Comment: Then I would use a try/catch in the insert logic. Do you use a stored procedure for your insert?

Comment: No, I don't use it.

Comment: Also, having the constraint on the database maintains data integrity. Triggers can be disabled.

Comment: With no procedure for inserts than put a try/catch in the application. You get the best of both worlds. Your data integrity is intact and you can provide users with the specific message you want.